# Apache Beam job on DataflowRunner never starts and no logs are generated- only on certain machines? WinError 10061

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run a simple Beam pipeline from Powershell.   The service account I am using has access to all the GCS buckets that it needs.  This works totally fine on my personal laptop, but on my work laptop I get the INFO output below and the job never shows up in the Dataflow console, also no logs are generated in GCP or anywhere else I can find.

I'm just wondering what could cause this on one laptop and not the other?

```
(virtualenv) PS C:\apps\beam> python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --input gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt --output gs://dw_json/counts --runner DataflowRunner --project 'inspired-studio-111111' --region 'us-west1' --temp_location gs://dw_json_temp/tmp/
INFO:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:Setting socket default timeout to 60 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:socket default timeout is 60.0 seconds.
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
```

EDIT
I was able to add some logging to output the traceback.   I found that a GCS bucket is not accessible by the app when the pipeline options are being validated

https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/dataflow-staging-us-central1-9b3b14cdbfe093a43e2e0e83d1f47d1e?alt=json

[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The service account that I am using in my local json key has full access to this bucket.

Any ideas what is blocking here?

Comment: Do you perhaps have multiple sets of credentials that are getting mixed up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `gsutil ls gs://dw_json/counts` works for you?  I wonder if it could be a similar issue to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2264 There's not much to go on here; perhaps you could add some additional logging to see how far it's making it.

Comment: gsutil ls gs//:dw_json/counts does indeed produce the expected results.   I see the word count output from when I ran the same command on my other laptop

Comment: Also I am not quite sure where to add logging as I cannot find any evidence that the execution of the python script ever begins.

Comment: You could add logging to wordcount.py, and if it makes it to the end of the with block, try adding some to dataflow_runner.py.